# Why is QTimer not signaling?

Tags: python, pyqt, qtimer

I have a simple setup where I need QTimer to update a label. Everything is fine, except the event never happens and the QTimer code is looked over.

```
def init_ui(self):
    self.sell_label = QLabel("Sale: " + str(self.bid))
    self.sell_label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.layout.addWidget(self.sell_label,7,9) 

    self.show()

    timer = QTimer()
    timer.timeout.connect(self.update_attrib) 
    timer.start(10000)         

def update_attrib(self):
    self.sell_label.setText("Sale" + " $100")
    self.sell_label.update()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your case is that the timer does not have a father so the garbage collector will eliminate it, before it the simplest thing is to pass a parent, in this case **self**.

```
timer = QTimer(self)
```

Or make it a class member:

```
self.timer = QTimer()
```

*Note:* You do not need to use the `update()`

Comment: Thank you. That was the issue.